# Make some noise-cancelling headphones

Tags: code-golf, audio

I am in desperate need of some ear defenders, so I can program in peace. Unfortunately, I don't have ear defenders. But I do have a pair of headphones, a microphone and a microcontroller, so I thought I'd make some noise-cancelling headphones.

However, there is one tiny problem. I can't program in noisy environments! So you'll need to write the code for me.

### Task

Given a constant noisy input, output the input's "complement"; a value that will completely cancel out the input value (`0x00` cancels `0xff`, `0x7f` cancels `0x80`). Because the headphones block *some* noise, also take a value as input that you will divide the "complement" by, using the following algorithm: [`if (c < 0x80) ceil ( 0x7f - ( (0x7f - c) / n ) ) else floor ( ( (c - 0x80) / n ) + 0x80 )`](//jsfiddle.net/wizzwizz4/Lovu4gqe/) where `c` is the "complement" and `n` is the value to divide by. (If the value exceeds the byte range, it should be clipped to `0` or `255`.)

The input will always be a sequence of bytes, via `stdin` or function parameter (see bonuses) but the modifier can be given via any input method. The output sequence should be output via `stdout` or as a return value (see bonuses). The output should be a series of bytes (e.g. `$.d<±3Ç/ó¢`), or a set of numbers representing those bytes (e.g. `217 135 21 43 126 219`).

Oh, and your code will have to be short, because there isn't much flash memory on the microcontroller (4096 bytes; and I need to fit on drivers too!).

### Examples

In these examples, I have used hexadecimal codes to represent bytes, because `DEL` and `NULL` are somewhat hard to read. The actual input and output should be done as a string of bytes or as a byte-stream.

Modifier: `2`
Input: `0x00 0x10 0xe0` ...
Output: `0xbf 0xb7 0x4f` ...

Modifier: `128`
Input: `0x00 0x10 0xe0` ...
Output: `0x80 0x80 0x7f` ...

Modifier: `0.5`
Input: `0x00 0x10 0xe0` ...
Output: `0xff 0xff 0x00` ...

Your code should cope with much longer inputs than this; these are just examples.

### Bonuses

To add a bonus to a score, use the following formula: `s * (100% - b)` where `s` is the current score and `b` is the bonus as a percentage.

- 1% If you output as raw bytes.
- 5% If there's no `stdin` pipe (or byte input), get the bytes straight from the microphone, [such as with `parec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269490/which-special-file-holds-microphone-input).
- 5% If you output to the speakers as well as returning / outputting to `stdout`.

Comment: Why require STDIN/STDOUT? I don't see a reason why we shouldn't be allowed to use function arguments/returns values instead.

Comment: Although, there is a good reason you shouldn't be allowed to; it would be a bit of a rubbish noise-canceller if there wasn't any cancelling until all the bytes had been received through the microphone!

Comment: What's a compliment? Is it like a complement?

Comment: Does the output have to be given in hex?

Comment: @xnor It has to **not** be given in Hex. I just didn't think it would be easy to read `NULL` and `DEL` characters. You need to output as a byte stream. (I'll update the question.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 What's a byte stream? Some languages have different data types and names. Will a number do?

Comment: @xnor An arbitrary-sized number or a string of bytes is an acceptable replacement for a byte-stream.

Comment: I'm assuming we can use an algorithm equivalent to the provided one if it's shorter?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Of course; this wouldn't be code-golf if you were just golfing my code!

Comment: Bonuses are generally discouraged in [tag:code-golf].

Comment: @lirtosiast That's why I didn't add bonuses for bonuses' sake. I only added bonuses that I thought would add to the challenge.

Comment: "An arbitrary-sized number or a string of bytes is an acceptable replacement for a byte-stream." By "string of bytes", do you mean my language's native String type, or a bunch of `byte`s strung together in an array?

Comment: @tac The string type is what I had in mind, but there's a problem with `NULL` and "end of string" in some languages.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 can you clarify in the question how the output format should be? the current spec is quite vague

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>54</s> 51 bytes

```
J128m.MZ,0h.mb,255?<dJ.E-tJc-tJdQs+c-dJQJm-255id16E
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J128m.MZ%2C0h.mb%2C255%3F%3CdJ.E-tJc-tJdQs%2Bc-dJQJm-255id16E&input=128%0A%5B%220x00%22%2C%220x10%22%2C%220xe0%22%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A%5B%220x00%22%2C%220x10%22%2C%220xe0%22%5D%0A128%0A%5B%220x00%22%2C%220x10%22%2C%220xe0%22%5D%0A0.5%0A%5B%220x00%22%2C%220x10%22%2C%220xe0%22%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

### Explanation

```
J128m.MZ,0h.mb,255?<dJ.E-tJc-tJdQs+c-dJQJm-255id16E   # Q = modifier, E = input list

J128                                                  # set J to 128
                                         m        E   # map each input d
                                              id16    # convert to decimal
                                          -255        # get the complement
    m                                                 # map each complement d
                  ?<dj                                # if d < 128
                      .E-tJc-tJdQ                     # use the ceil-formula
                                 s+c-dJQJ             # otherwise use the floor-formular
          .mb,255                                     # minimum of the result and 255
    .MZ,0h                                            # maximum of the result and 0
```